# Not able to use tor and curl, for a specific website

Tags: curl, tor

If I run

```
curl -L -v --socks5-hostname localhost:9050 https://unix.stackexchange.com/
```

I get back the stackexchange webpage.

If I use the below URL

```
curl -L -v --socks5-hostname localhost:9050 https://www.comune.bitonto.ba.it/
```

I get this error

```
* SOCKS5 connect to www.comune.bitonto.ba.it:443 (remotely resolved)
* Can't complete SOCKS5 connection to www.comune.bitonto.ba.it. (1)
* Closing connection 0
curl: (97) Can't complete SOCKS5 connection to www.comune.bitonto.ba.it. (1)
```

What could I change to figure out what blocks my command?

I'm using `curl 7.74.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.74.0 OpenSSL/1.1.1n zlib/1.2.11 brotli/1.0.9 libidn2/2.3.0 libpsl/0.21.0 (+libidn2/2.3.0) libssh2/1.9.0 nghttp2/1.43.0 librtmp/2.3`

Comment: It does not work for me either. One likely reason I can think of is www.comune.bitonto.ba.it is blocking connections from tor nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the website [www.comune.bitonto.ba.it](http://www.comune.bitonto.ba.it) does not allow connection through tor nodes.

I grepped my syslog to see what tor was doing

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep tor -i
```

and this is what I got

```
Dec  5 19:21:06 pop-os Tor[32400]: We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $5D17014B40C448DE04030533357199B3E3C4311F~artikel10ber62 [ApwndvRaO0PmthZdLf566dscdKTInkedTWK3WMvFyfs] at 185.220.101.31. Retrying on a new circuit.
Dec  5 19:21:21 pop-os Tor[32400]: We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $1808CDA40FDEFE9F1A117F89477BADC882C08A63~ferrarizSchumacher [DW2ogtbJfUbT7FCLnfkTsOWYMcC9i2sA/7GS65ZeOBM] at 193.105.134.150. Retrying on a new circuit.
Dec  5 19:21:36 pop-os Tor[32400]: We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $8287DADC415B3E667C617EEFB6E7D654C7AC0C47~Digitalcourage4ip4b [SHHyLj7Vgq47KP1s5grU4sAzHOmeu3KG4fl0vxEva+E] at 185.220.102.251. Retrying on a new circuit.
Dec  5 19:21:51 pop-os Tor[32400]: We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $B580111855B9C452EB224CA7932B626E28D3C2EA~mwittig [jfvKL/a/V8MG4OEyoL2xzv9rYQuYPnFYAyoqKG2Pt7Q] at 185.235.146.29. Retrying on a new circuit.
Dec  5 19:22:06 pop-os Tor[32400]: We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $6E16D38C5AC170E5608817B66625C5F34F21D96E~ForPrivacyNET [JjbRuOYiio80hkr2DMvVZou8bwncmoeFmb0ZvQ6Dn1E] at 185.220.101.59. Retrying on a new circuit.
Dec  5 19:22:21 pop-os Tor[32400]: We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $E2B28C0F45A3139AF5F7D4DC4B5D16C634E310C5~mev3PLicebeer77 [TeEAUPjmul98ZpxYsdntiZn90N2YDB44J83Y4swhsPg] at 95.214.52.208. Retrying on a new circuit.
Dec  5 19:22:36 pop-os Tor[32400]: We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $E8C8667CAF3D5148E52ECF736A7B204982F78EAA~F3Netze [Czc9qIZzJbWBh5rxuvc/KX3NF4biZWOIHri5FtWVPRs] at 185.220.100.254. Retrying on a new circuit.
Dec  5 19:22:36 pop-os Tor[32400]: Tried for 125 seconds to get a connection to [scrubbed]:443. Giving up.
```